# Supplied argument is not a valid MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
$qs = 'SELECT cnam,COUNT(*) as cnt FROM cdr WHERE '.$where.' GROUP BY COUNT(*)';
$objRs = mysql_query($qs);
while($obj = mysql_fetch_array($objRs))
{
    if ($obj['cnam'])
    {
        $names[$obj['cnam']]['call_name'] += $obj['cnt'];
    }
}

foreach($names as $h=>$count)
{
    if ($h)
    {
        echo '<operator name="'.$h.'" '.($count['call_name'] ? 'callcenter="'.$count['call_name'].'"' : "").'></operator>';
    }
}
echo '</operators>';
```

what am I doing wrong with it? It says that problem is right here:

> mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL

```
while($obj = mysql_fetch_array($objRs))
```

Havent any idea where's my mistake here.

Comment: you forgot to give database connection link in $objRs = mysql_query($qs,$link);

Comment: what do you get if you `print $qs;` ?

Comment: it's just sample of code, i did it higher a bit.

Comment: You might be getting an `Error : 1056` over here. You can't use `group` on **'COUNT(*)'**

Comment: `GROUP BY COUNT(*)` is the problem you have to write `GROUP BY COLUNM NAME` also show us the value of `$where` variable

Comment: stop using `mysql_` functions as they are deprecated.. Start using `PDO` or `mysqli_` functions

Answer (score 3):

You cannot `group by` an aggregation function.  I think you intend:

```
SELECT cnam, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM cdr
WHERE '.$where.'
GROUP BY cnam;
```

Comment: and here's answer when i'm trying
`error on line 1 at column 1517: Encoding error`

Answer (score 2):

There must be an error in query 
write `echo mysql_error();` before

```
while($obj = mysql_fetch_array($objRs))
```

this will give you a better idea of where your query is having error.

Comment: `This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1517: Encoding error`

Is it troubles with my sql data or something? I can take only one field without GROUP BY and when i'm trying to take a list here it comes. Thanks for tryin' guys

Comment: Can you past your complete code of your file in question

Comment: **You can only post once every 90 minutes.**
it's not time yet